# Functions starting before the form is loading

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to do stuff that requires internet as soon as my form loads.
Now my problem is that the functions with internet (meaning it takes a bit) start before the form is actually loaded.

I can't use a backgroundworker so I need another alternative to get my form to load before the functions start.

```
public IntroForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartChecking();
}
```

Comment: why can't you use backgroundworker?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't put `StartChecking()` in the `Form_Shown` or `Form_Load` events so you can guarantee the form is already loaded?

Comment: Because I was too dumb to think of that, thanks drew ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use BackgroundWorker you can use TPL like that:

```
public IntroForm() 
{     
    InitializeComponent();     
    Task.Factory.StartNew(StartChecking);
}
```